# iOS error using JSON and php

Tags: ios, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am attempting to use JSON to parse some output from a php file that will hopefully return some data from my MySQL db. However, I am getting the error: -JSONValue failed. Error is: Illegal start of token [A]. The php script returns an array of dictionaries for plotting annotations on a map. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (void)getDeviceLocations {

    NSLog(@"Getting Device Locations");

    NSString *hostStr = @"http://98.246.50.81/firecom/api/getdevicelocations.php";
    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:hostStr]];
    NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    id object = [serverOutput JSONValue];
    NSMutableArray *array = (NSMutableArray *)object;

    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array) {

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {[[dictionary objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue], [[dictionary objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue]};

        Annotation *ann = [[Annotation alloc] init];
        ann.title = [dictionary objectForKey:@"deviceid"];
        ann.coordinate = coord;
        [mapView addAnnotation:ann];
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the json, I think that is an invalid json

Comment: I visited the url and here it is what retured:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [deviceid] => E19 iPad [latitude] => 45.511293 [longitude] => -122.800233 ) [1] => Array ( [deviceid] => E05 iPad [latitude] => 45.54580829752314 [longitude] => -122.9588931798935 ) [2] => Array ( [deviceid] => E01 iPad [latitude] => 45.520697139998525 [longitude] => -122.98941537737846 ) )

I think it's not a valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, your JSON is not valid. You should return a valid JSON like this (using your data)

```
[
  {
    "latitude": 45.5113,
    "deviceid": "E19 iPad",
    "longitude": "-122.800233"
  },
  {
    "latitude": 45.5458,
    "deviceid": "E05 iPad",
    "longitude": "-122.9588931798935"
  },
  {
    "latitude": 45.5207,
    "deviceid": "E01 iPad",
    "longitude": "-122.98941537737846"
  }
]
```

I think it's better to try to use the [default php JSON encode method json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to generate json string.

Comment: I fixed my own problem. I didn't realize I had to echo json_encode($output). That fixed it.